# PHPCodeSniffer HTML Report?

Tags: php, reporting, phpcodesniffer

Does PHPCodeSniffer generates HTML Report?

If not? How?

Currently, I can run PHPCodeSniffer but it only produce XML file and displays result in the terminal.

How can I make produce HTML Report like the coverage and unit test report in phpunit.

Currently I use PHPCheckStyle since it produces html report, but i want also to try PHPCodeSniffer to know which is best.

Comment: Sorry for that question. What I meant for that is If PHPCodeSniffer does not generate HTML Report, how can we do it so that it will produce HTML report, is there a way? or will i just wait for future versions that supports that functionality... I apologize for that invalid question.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831535/how-can-i-convert-php-code-sniffer-xml-report-into-html which has a real answer to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution (but maybe not the simplest one) is to use a **continuous integration system** that provides PHP code sniffer integration.

For example, [**phpUnderControl**](http://phpundercontrol.org/screenshots/full/0.3.2-codesniffer.html) provides a nice interface to see the report.

[image: phpUnderControl]

Answer (score 2):

HTML Reporting is not provided yet. However there is a workaround to get the job done.

You can export the report to XML and read the data with DOM Parser and generate an HTML version on your own. [Here is a quick tutorial to get you started.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Writing your own report is pretty trivial actually.

If you are running from CLI you can implement your own report class with a unique method and call it from command ligne. For a report named Xxx :

```
class PHP_CodeSniffer_Reports_Xxx implements PHP_CodeSniffer_Report
{ 

  /**
   * Prints all errors and warnings for each file processed.
   *
   * Errors and warnings are displayed together, grouped by file.
   *
   * @param array   $report      Prepared report.
   * @param boolean $showSources Show sources?
   * @param int     $width       Maximum allowed lne width.
   * @param boolean $toScreen    Is the report being printed to screen?
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function generate(
      $report,
      $showSources=false,
      $width=80,
      $toScreen=true
  ) {
     ...
  }
}
```

If your are running from a web server, the `PHP_CodeSniffer.getFilesErrors()` method gives you a nice array of errors with all you need to produce a report.

Answer (score -1):

HTML Reporting is working for me. Just use according --help:

```
phpcs src/AppBundle --generator=HTML > index.html
```

Show the result in index.html

Comment: Generator is used to force create documentation of your rules, not for generating report in HTML - see doc: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Usage <generator>    Uses either the "HTML", "Markdown" or "Text" generator
                (forces documentation generation instead of checking)

you could use report now but it's not support HTML - <report>       Print either the "full", "xml", "checkstyle", "csv"
                "json", "junit", "emacs", "source", "summary", "diff"
                "svnblame", "gitblame", "hgblame" or "notifysend" report