# PHP_CodeSniffer: How to reset line length on newline?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I've made a custom standard because my coding style is far from anything anyone would call normal. In fact, I reject about 90% of what many people consider good standards as whitespace spam. That being said, I do think that if I'm going to use a slightly odd coding style I should at least be consistently odd. To that end, I've copied all of the `Generic` standard sniffs into my custom standard and I'm now modifying\removing those to suit my needs.

The issue I'm having ATM is that I'm trying to find\modify a sniff that will actually limit line length in the manner we are all used to when measuring line length. The current sniff I'm using (which is from the `Generic` standard so I'm assuming that is the most commonly used) does not reset the count when a newline is encountered.

An example of what is happening (for the purpose of this I'm using very small limits):

```
$var='789012345678'.
  '2345678';
```

Currently, if I have a limit of 20 characters this snippet will produce an error because it doesn't reset the count until it reaches a semi-colon (;). I need this to pass unless >20 characters are all on a **single** actual line (IOW: it needs to reset when it encounters a new line instead of a semicolon).

Note: I **do not** want to [disable the line length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280716/how-to-ignore-line-length-php-codesniffer) sniff altogether.

UPDATE: Someone just posted an answer to this question which led me directly to the solution. I was going to accept that answer but it has been deleted now. I'll give them some time to rewrite the previous answer if they want before I post the solution myself. HINT: it had to do with using the `Generic` standard. It could've also been improved had they mentioned that it is the PEAR standard which doesn't use newlines; others seem to work normally.

Comment: Hm, _all_ standards here work normally (resets after newline, not `;`), in PHP_CodeSniffer version 1.4.7, which version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I've found that out now. I believe that issue was a side effect of doing things in a completely incorrect manner but I've been unable to reproduce it since I've rearranged how I'm doing this. I wasn't supposed to copy sniffs from somewhere else I was supposed to use the ruleset.xml file to define which items to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem it is because the `Generic` standard is not meant to be used as a standard. While this isn't exactly what  was doing it was effectively the same because I had copied all of the sniffs from it to begin with. Some of the sniffs it includes directly conflict with each other. It is definitely a shortcoming of the library that it produced such erroneous results due to this but it wouldn't have been a problem had I used them correctly (by importing the sniffs I wanted individually into my custom standard definition file).